# Tar compress files when some can be missing

Tags: bash, ubuntu, tar

I am writing a bash script that pulls files from another server to the current directory. The issue is that I get a lot of files and I only need ~3 of them; however all 3 might not be there.

For example, make server all:

```
server call --> file1.txt file2.txt file3.xls file4.json .... (etc)
```

Then compress files with tar:

```
tar zcf needed_files.tgz file4.json file23.doc *.txt
```

But `file4.json` was not there, so I would expect tar to compress `file23.doc` and all `.txt` files but the script fails with:

```
tar: file4.json: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

I have tried other combinations of tar commands like `czvf` but no luck.

Comment: `tar zcf needed_files.tgz file4.json file23.doc *.txt 2>/dev/null` should work

Comment: I hesitate to throw away all error output because one known possibility is acceptable... though it *would* take more code to filter out just the case(s) we don't care about. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

`tar` should successfully compress the existing files despite the *"no such file or directory"* errors.

Anyway, you could also use [`nullglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) in combination with [`extglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) `@()` to get only the existing files:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
files=( "fileA"@() "fileB"@() *.txt )

(( ${#files[@]} )) && tar zcf needed_files.tgz -- "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Could be the OP has a `set -e` they aren't telling us about, making the condition fatal. Or just that they have a different `tar` implementation (as it's not a POSIX-specified tool, behavior can vary between implementations).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right, I didnt think of that :)

Answer (score 2):

Try an extended glob.

```
shopt -s extglob # set extended globbing on
if echo file[1234].+(txt|xls|json) | grep -vq '\['
then tar cvzf needed_files.tgz file[1234].+(txt|xls|json)
else echo No matching files for extglob 'file[1234].+(txt|xls|json)'
fi
```

If matching files exist, it will list them.

If not, it will literally echo back the pattern.

grepping out the pattern metacharacters tells you whether there are any files in the set. If they do exist, use the same glob to provide the files to tar, and it will receive exactly the set of matching files. If they don't, the condition test lets you skip it.

Of course, it breaks if you make files with `[` in the names, etc...

Or, you could do it in a loop....

```
for f in file[1234].+(txt|xls|json)
do if [[ -e "$f" ]]
   then [[ -e needed_files.tar ]] && c=r || c=c
        tar ${c}vf needed_files.tar "$f"
   fi
done
```

Not perfect, but might suit your tastes better.

Neither is a great solution, but one of them ought to get you rolling.

Answer (score 2):

```
tar zcf needed_files.tgz $(ls -d file4.json file23.doc *.txt 2>/dev/null)
```

Notice that prints only existing files

```
ls -d file4.json file23.doc *.txt 2>/dev/null
```

Also you can use `--ignore-failed-read` option, but it will also ignore other read errors.

Comment: `--ignore-failed-read` is a blessing :)